# Simple telnet session fails on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, smtp

I am learning `Postfix` and how it works with `SMTP`, and here's a sample session that the book shows as an example:

[image]

I ran the command `hostname` on my Mac terminal, and it showed `<some_id>.ant.amazon.com` (it is my office laptop). So I tried

```
telnet  <id>.ant.amazon.com 25
```

And I got the error message:

```
<id>.ant.amazon.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Then I tried `telnet 10.232.45.151 25` as well. It showed the message **Trying 10.232.45.151...** for a long time before quitting with the message:

```
telnet: connect to address 10.232.45.151: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I tried `telnet localhost 25` as well, with this output:

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I have a session like the one shown in the picture?

Comment: Are you sure your mail server is running (on port 25)? That might be the problem. Also, you can use `localhost` instead if you want to connect to your own computer.

Comment: That failed as well. See edit. I don't have any mail server running per se. I just fired up my terminal and ran these commands..

Comment: Well if you don't have a mail server running on your own machine then how do you expect to connect to it? I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: How do I configure my Mac to run as a mail server? I thought that was what the book is going to teach me!

Comment: I have no idea how Telnet works or what it does, this example was given in the very first chapter itself, so I figured I will try it..

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a mail server running then there is nothing listening on port 25. Thus connection refused messages. So you need to run the mail server first.

Also unless you work for Amazon your hostname is not .ant.amazon.com  If you do ask your network admins.

And this bit is a comment - I think you need to learn what telnet does before you start trying to run services.

Comment: Yes, of course, I thought that I will follow the examples in the book verbatim, and will learn as I proceed..So how do I run a mail server on my Mac?

Comment: @Cupidvogel how to run a mail server would be a separate question. Thanks!

Comment: If I follow the instructions here - https://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Mac_OS_X_Unleashed&seqNum=223, will it work? That is, once I follow the example and get a mail server up and running (using the in-built `sendmail`), will the example here work?

Comment: I suspect it will but the comment I made is more saying that unless you know Unix including telnet then you will have problems if something does not go exactly correctly. Also why do you want a mail server?